# MIPS Cross Compilation on Travis

Tags: c, ubuntu, mips, cross-compiling, travis-ci

How would one setup a `.travis.yml` to do cross compilation for MIPS target ? For PowerPC, this is trivial:

```
addons:
    apt:
      packages:
         - gcc-powerpc-linux-gnu
```

Since I have access to the package [directly](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/devel/gcc-powerpc-linux-gnu).

For MIPS I cannot find a compiler for it in Ubuntu Trusty:

- [Software Packages in "trusty", Subsection devel](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/devel/)

Even though it appears to be whitelisted:

- https://github.com/travis-ci/apt-package-whitelist/commit/5761eccc#diff-3583c6522a64da63a272436df8de85ceR1311

It seems I would need an updated Ubuntu image (not possible on Travis):

- [GNU C compiler for the mips architecture](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/devel/gcc-mips-linux-gnu)

The alternate solution would be to use some pre-build MIPS compiler, eg:

- [Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2013.11-36 for MIPS GNU/Linux](https://sourcery.mentor.com/GNUToolchain/release2640)

But documentation rather explicitely says not to cache those things:

- [Caching Dependencies and Directories#Things not to cache](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/#Things-not-to-cache)

> **Large files** that are quick to install but slow to download do **not**
>   benefit from caching, as they take as long to download from the cache
>   as from the original source:
>
> - Android SDKs
> - Debian packages
> - JDK packages
> - **Compiled binaries**
> - Docker images

How would you install a mips cross compiler on the default Ubuntu Travis image ?

---

Update I tried a naive solution:

```
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
    - debian-sid
    packages:
    - gcc-mips-linux-gnu
```

But this fails with:

```
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-7-base_7.2.0-18_amd64.deb' has premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-7-base_7.2.0-18_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
```

It seems [dpkg](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/dpkg.html) in Ubuntu/Trusty will not support those deb files:

- [xz compressed control.tar files not supported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/1730627)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I cannot use container based because of this requirement, I gave up and simply used:

```
sudo: true
dist: trusty

addons:
  apt:
    packages:
    - u-boot-tools

before_install:
  - sudo add-apt-repository -y "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main universe"
  - sudo apt-get -qq update
  - sudo apt-get install -qq gcc-mips-linux-gnu
```

I am still intrigued by the fact that `gcc-mips-linux-gnu` is explicitly white-listed.